# Easy way to remove accents from a Unicode string?

Tags: java, string, unicode, diacritics

I want to change this sentence :

> Et ça sera sa moitié.

To :

> Et ca sera sa moitie.

Is there an easy way to do this in Java, like I would do in Objective-C ?

```
NSString *str = @"Et ça sera sa moitié.";
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Finally, I've solved it by using the `Normalizer` class.

```
import java.text.Normalizer;

public static String stripAccents(String s) 
{
    s = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    s = s.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");
    return s;
}
```

Comment: In order to correctly transform some strings, I used **`Form.NFKD`** ("Compatibility decomposition.")

Comment: It seems that Normalizer is deprecated and Normalizer2 should be use instead http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Normalizer2.html

Comment: @ykatchou, what makes you believe `java.text.Normalizer` to be deprecated?

Comment: See here : http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Normalizer.html ("This API has been replaced by the Normalizer2 class and is only available for backward compatibility")

Comment: @ykatchou you refer to "com.ibm.icu.text.Normalizer", but answer is about "java.text.Normalizer"

Comment: But it changes the sense of text on different languages: stripAccents("йод,ëлка,wäre") //иод,елка,ware. How to remove only acute accents? Or any selected set of diacritics?

Answer (score 122):

Maybe the easiest and safest way is using `StringUtils` from [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang)

```
StringUtils.stripAccents(String input)
```

> Removes diacritics (~= accents) from a string. The case will not be
>   altered. For instance, 'à' will be replaced by 'a'. Note that
>   ligatures will be left as is.

StringUtils.[stripAccents()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents%28java.lang.String%29%60)

Comment: Note that it's Apache Commons Lang3, not Commons Lang

Comment: It's good, but will not work for 'Ø'.

Comment: Selected answer doesn't eliminate polish `ł` and `Ł` from string, this one does.

Comment: Elegant and short way!

Answer (score 12):

I guess the only difference is that I use a `+` and not a `[]` compared to the solution. I think both works, but it's better to have it here as well.

```
String normalized = Normalizer.normalize(input, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
String accentRemoved = normalized.replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", "");
```

Answer (score 7):

For kotlin

```
fun stripAccents(s: String): String 
{
    var string = Normalizer.normalize(s, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
    string = Regex("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+").replace(string, "")
    return  string
}
```

Comment: great but it would be better with an extension function of String

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are using Java 6 or newer, you might want to take a look at [`Normalizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html), which can decompose accents, then use a regex to strip the combining accents.

Otherwise, you should be able to achieve the same result using [`ICU4J`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Normalizer.html).