# Normalize a string except ñ

Tags: java, normalize

I have the following example code:

```
String n = "Péña";
n = Normalizer.normalize(n, Normalizer.Form.NFC);
```

How do I normalize the string `n` excepting the `ñ`?

And not only that string, I'm making a form and I want to keep just the `ñ's`, and everything else without diacritics.

Comment: Just `normalize` and then change back the normalied `n~` to `ñ`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace all occurrences of "ñ" with a non-printable character "\001", so "Péña" becomes "Pé\001a".  Then call `Normalizer.normalize()` to decompose the "é" into "e" and a separate diacritical mark.  Finally remove the diacritical marks, and convert the non-printable character back to "ñ".

```
String partiallyNormalize(String string)
{
    string = string.replace('ñ', '\001');
    string = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    string = string.replaceAll("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}]", "");
    string = string.replace('\001', 'ñ');
    return string;
}
```

You might also want to upvote the preferred answer to [Easy way to remove UTF-8 accents from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190656/easy-way-to-remove-utf-8-accents-from-a-string), where I learned how to remove the diacritical marks.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.