# Remove accents in string except "ñ"

Tags: c#, regex, normalization, utf-16

I have the following example code:

```
var inputString = "ñaáme";
inputString = inputString.Replace('ñ', '\u00F1');
var normalizedString = inputString.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
var result = Regex.Replace(normalizedString, @"[^ñÑa-zA-Z0-9\s]*", string.Empty);
return result.Replace('\u00F1', 'ñ'); // naame :(
```

I need to normalize the text without removing the "ñ"s

[I followed this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36098063/normalize-a-string-except-%C3%B1)
 But it's for Java and it has not worked for me

I want your result to be: "ñaame".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may match any Unicode letter other than your specific letter `ñ` and ASCII letters (that do not need normalization) with `(?i)[\p{L}-[ña-z]]+` regex and normalize it. Then, also remove any combining marks from the string.

Use

```
var inputString = "ñaáme";
var result = string.Concat(Regex.Replace(inputString, @"(?i)[\p{L}-[ña-z]]+", m => 
        m.Value.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
    )
    .Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark));
Console.Write(result);
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Iy3Or1)

**Pattern description**

- `(?i)` - ignore case modifier
- `[` - start of a character class

  - `\p{L}` - any Unicode letter
  - `-[` - other than

    - `ña-z` - `ñ` and ASCII letters
  - `]` - end of the subtraction class
- `]+` - 1 or more occurrences.

Comment: Your answer is very good. I worked his code.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure, I never would have come to the solution that way, and that I saw some Regular Expressions.
Again, thank you very much.