# How to replace encoded characters to string literals? like \uDXYZW or something like that?

Tags: java, string, text, unicode, utf-8

I have the following code in Java to replace the characters with tildes like:

```
á é í ó ú Á É Í Ó Ú à è ì ò ù À È Ì Ò Ù 

text = text.replace( "Ã¡", "a" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã©", "e" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã­", "i" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã³", "o" );
    text = text.replace( "Ãº", "u" );

    // caracteres raros: tildes mayusculas
    text = text.replace( "Ã", "A" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã‰", "E" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã", "I" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã“", "O" );
    text = text.replace( "Ãš", "U" );


    // caracteres raros: tildes inversas minusculas
    text = text.replace( "Ã ", "a" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã¨", "e" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã¬", "i" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã²", "o" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã¹", "u" );

    // caracteres raros: tildes inversas mayusculas
    text = text.replace( "Ã€", "A" );
    text = text.replace( "Ãˆ", "E" );
    text = text.replace( "ÃŒ", "I" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã’", "O" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã™", "U" );

    // caracteres raros: ñ minuscula y mayuscula
    text = text.replace( "Ã‘", "n" );
    text = text.replace( "Ã±", "N" );
```

I want to use a notation like:

```
text = text.replace( "\uD1232", "N" );
```

But i don't know where to find a table with that characters: `... Ã€, Ãˆ, ÃŒ ...`

Comment: You shouldn't do this manually, use [`Normalizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html) instead; that's what it's designed for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to remove UTF-8 accents from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190656/easy-way-to-remove-utf-8-accents-from-a-string)

Answer (score 0):

The JDK contains a tool named [`native2ascii`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html).

Create a text file in UTF-8 encoding with the special characters.

For example file `in.txt`:

```
á é í ó ú Á É Í Ó Ú à è ì ò ù À È Ì Ò Ù
```

Then call:

```
native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 in.txt out.txt
```

After that your file `out.txt` contains the escape sequences like that:

```
\u00e1 \u00e9 \u00ed \u00f3 \u00fa \u00c1 \u00c9 \u00cd \u00d3 \u00da \u00e0 \u00e8 \u00ec \u00f2 \u00f9 \u00c0 \u00c8 \u00cc \u00d2 \u00d9
```

Answer (score 0):

Part seems to be originally UTF-8 encoded text erroneously interpreted as maybe ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) or such.

The following is a successfull attempt to repair it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    p1("Ã ", "a");
    p1("Ã\u00a0", "a"); // Non-breaking space instead
    p1("Ã¨", "e");
    p1("Ã¬", "i");
    p1("Ã²", "o");
    p1("Ã¹", "u");

    // caracteres raros: tildes inversas mayusculas
    p1("Ã€", "A");
    p1("Ãˆ", "E");
    p1("ÃŒ", "I");
    p1("Ã’", "O");
    p1("Ã™", "U");

    // caracteres raros: ñ minuscula y mayuscula
    p1("Ã‘", "n");
    p1("Ã±", "N");
}

static void p1(String s, String t) {
    String v = new String(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String u = Normalizer.normalize(v, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\pM", "");
    if (u.equalsIgnoreCase(t)) {
        System.out.printf("[1] %s -> %s :: %s%n", v, u, t);
    } else {
        p2(s, t);
    }
}

static void p2(String s, String t) {
    String v = new String(s.getBytes(Charset.forName("Windows-1252")),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    String u = Normalizer.normalize(v, Normalizer.Form.NFD)
            .replaceAll("\\pM", "");
    System.out.printf("[2] %s -> %s :: %s%n", v, u, t);
}

[2] �  -> �  -> a
[1] à -> a :: a
[1] è -> e :: e
[1] ì -> i :: i
[1] ò -> o :: o
[1] ù -> u :: u
[2] À -> A -> A
[2] È -> E -> E
[2] Ì -> I -> I
[2] Ò -> O -> O
[2] Ù -> U -> U
[2] Ñ -> N -> n
[1] ñ -> n :: N
```

As you can see n/N is evidently mixed up. and the first entry with the space is evidently corrupted. `s = s.replace(' ', '\u00a0');` would do.

The code above uses a Normalizer to throw away the accents, by splitting accented letters in basic letter and combining diacritical marks. Removing the latter by replaceAll.

- UTF-8 is a Unicode charset
- ISO-8859-1 is Latin-1, subset of UTF-8
- Windows-1252 is Windows Latin-1, a "superset" of Latin-1.

(The code above might best be edited and compiled in a java source with UTF-8 encoding to not have surprises.)