# Spark replace characters AąCć

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, regexp-replace

I used the translate method in spark but I would like to have the same with using the spark regex (replace etc.). Could you Please help to re-write it?

```
df.withColumn(„name_surname”,translate(col(„name_surname”),”ĄąĆcĘeŁłŹźŻŚśÓóŃń”,”AaCcEeLlZzZSsOoNn”))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's no Spark function to do that, but you can always one of plain Java methods, eg. as suggested in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190656/easy-way-to-remove-accents-from-a-unicode-string), then wrap it in a UDF.

```scala
val stripAccents = udf(org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.stripAccents(_))
df.withColumn("name_surname", stripAccents($"name_surname")).show

+-----------------+
|     name_surname|
+-----------------+
|AaCcEeLlZzZSsOoNn|
+-----------------+
```