# Converting Non-ASCII code to ASCII equivalent in terms of look

Tags: converters, non-ascii-characters, extended-ascii

I have thousands of name in a mysql database that have the extended ASCII code in them. I want to convert them to a normal english alphabet. Here is an example :

Indāpur Jejūri    convert to ->   Indapur Jejuri

So how can I do it ? I know Java and Groovy, and a bunch of other scripting languages but didn't have much luck. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Presumably you'd get a 64K-entry translation table and translate.

Comment: Python has [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode), which probably has some sort of Java equivalent.

Comment: PHP answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer after going through many posts in stackoverflow : [Converting Symbols, Accent Letters to English Alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008802/converting-symbols-accent-letters-to-english-alphabet)

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public String deAccent(String str) {
    String nfdNormalizedString = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFD); 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+");
    return pattern.matcher(nfdNormalizedString).replaceAll("");
}
```