# Android Phone Contacts

Tags: android

I want to get the Contact name of the selected contact in android while working with default contacts of phone.
I tried like this but it show all the contact names in the phone but i want only selected contact name

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phNumber));

                    // query time
                    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null, null, null);

                    if(cursor != null) {
                        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            name =      cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            Log.v("sai", "Started uploadcontactphoto: Contact Found @ " + phNumber);            
                            Log.v("sai", "Started uploadcontactphoto: Contact name  = " + name);
                        } else {
                            Log.v("sai", "Contact Not Found @ " + phNumber);
                        }
                        cursor.close();
                    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by selected contact name?

Comment: whenever the default contact page is opened in my app the user has to click on one contact.then i want to display that contact details in another activity.

Comment: If you want to show the details then you can store the details in arraylist and then pass the details into another activity to show there.

Comment: What details you want to show.

Comment: can you please post the code for storing the contact details in arraylist.I want to show the all details of the contact

Answer (score 0):

So, you're using the right approach, but you aren't telling Android what specific contact to look up.

You don't state what a "selected contact" is, but I assume you should know its phone number or some such by which to actually query the contact list.

According to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal%29), you're just not using the selection parameters.

You can write selection param just as you would an SQL query's WHERE statement. As in
    ContactsContract.PhoneLookup + " = 123456789"

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2158589/1760858) answer for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in which i am storing the email address and contact person name in arraylist

```
public ArrayList<ContactVo> getNameEmailDetails() {
        ArrayList<ContactVo> m_arrList = new ArrayList<ContactVo>();
        ArrayList<String> emlRecs = new ArrayList<String>();
        HashSet<String> emlRecsHS = new HashSet<String>();
        ContentResolver cr = m_context.getContentResolver();
        String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };
        String order = "CASE WHEN " + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " NOT LIKE '%@%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, "
                + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ", "
                + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA
                + " COLLATE NOCASE";
        String filter = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA
                + " NOT LIKE ''";
        Cursor cur = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION,
                filter, null, order);
        ContactVo m_vo;
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                m_vo = new ContactVo();
                // names comes in hand sometimes
                String name = cur.getString(1);
                String emlAddr = cur.getString(3);
                System.err.println("Value Is---------->" + cur.getString(2)
                        + "Name--" + name + "Email---" + emlAddr);
                m_vo.setM_sName(name);
                m_vo.setM_sEmail(emlAddr);
                // keep unique only
                if (emlRecsHS.add(emlAddr.toLowerCase())) {
                    emlRecs.add(emlAddr);
                }
                m_arrList.add(m_vo);
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
        }

        cur.close();
        return m_arrList;
    }
```

**EDITED:**

Write the below code in your onItemClick event of your listview where you are showing all the contact list.

```
m_lvList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            Toast.makeText(m_context, m_arrContact.get(arg2).getM_sEmail(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent in = new Intent(m_context, Test.class);
            in.putExtra("pos", arg2);
            in.putParcelableArrayListExtra("parcel", m_arrContact);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
```

Make your vo parcelable to pass the details into another activity and access it.

**ContactVo**

```
    public class ContactVo implements Parcelable {
    private String m_sName, m_sEmail;

    public ContactVo() {
    }

    public ContactVo(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public String getM_sName() {
        return m_sName;
    }

    public void setM_sName(String m_sName) {
        this.m_sName = m_sName;
    }

    public String getM_sEmail() {
        return m_sEmail;
    }

    public void setM_sEmail(String m_sEmail) {
        this.m_sEmail = m_sEmail;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(m_sName);
        dest.writeString(m_sEmail);

    }

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel p_in) {

        m_sName = p_in.readString();
        m_sEmail = p_in.readString();
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContactVo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ContactVo>() {
        public ContactVo createFromParcel(Parcel s) {
            return new ContactVo(s);
        }

        public ContactVo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ContactVo[size];
        }
    };

}
```

In your another activity write as below:

```
public class Test extends Activity {

    ArrayList<ContactVo> m_arr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

        m_arr = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("parcel");
        int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 0);
        System.out.println("Detailsss------>" + m_arr.get(pos).getM_sEmail()
                + m_arr.get(pos).getM_sName());

    }

}
```

You can add as many details as much you want into the `ArrayList<ContactVo>` and pass it into another activity.

To get other contact details Check out [HERE](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/06/get-phone-contacts-details-in-android_6.html)